# How using the result of a powershell function affects the behavior of this function?

Tags: powershell

I have this strange observation, which does not make much sense to me.

Please, examine the following trivial powershell script:

```
function f($x)
{
  Write-Host "Opening $x in the GUI" -ForegroundColor yellow
  cmd /c start devenv $x
  return $true
}
f "C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\DataSvc.sln"
f "C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\Main.sln"
echo "done"
```

Running it, fires the two devenv instances right away and the script exits almost immediately.

Now I modify it slightly:

```
function f($x)
{
  Write-Host "Opening $x in the GUI" -ForegroundColor yellow
  cmd /c start devenv $x
  return $true
}
$a = f "C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\DataSvc.sln"
$b = f "C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\Main.sln"
echo "done"
```

Running it opens the first devenv instance, however, the function f never exists until I close that devenv instance. Then the second devenv instance is fired and the script never exists until I close that second devenv instance too.

The behavior is completely different. From the asynchronous it became totally synchronous.

What is going on?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the main question, but in this case, why bother to call `cmd.exe`? You should be able to start `devenv` with: `Start-Process devenv $x`

Answer (score 0):

Powershell pipelines execute asynchronously when the last command is an external command and the result is not being piped.

That's what happens in the first case.

If you pipe or use the result as in an assignment to a variable, the pipeline executes synchronously.

That's what happens in the second case.